# clear viewport in wpf

Tags: wpf, viewport

I create a model (cube) and add that to my viewport and it works properly without any problem.

this.mainViewport.Children.Add(model);

whenever I use the following code, the cube become black instead of it's original color.

this.mainViewport.Children.Clear();
this.mainViewport.Children.Add(model);

I need to clear the viewport as I am adding the cube in another position in next second. any suggestion to solve that problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the Color contained in the mainViewPort? I don't think you should clear the Children. The Viewport has other things independent of the objects like light, Transform ect. Why do you need to Clear()?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I need to change the position of the cube (in a data file, I have different 3D points and I changed the position of the cube based those points, I create a timer and read the next data based on the timer and visualize the object accordingly), I though that it was the easiest way to do that. any suggestions

Comment: here is my code:
ModelVisual3D model = new ModelVisual3D();
model.Content = cube;
this.mainViewport.Children.Clear();
this.mainViewport.Children.Add(model);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this instead :
Create the Cube first time in it start location :

```
ModelVisual3D model = new ModelVisual3D();
model.Content = cube;
```

Then in the timer I would change the Transform wit the new location:

```
model.Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(X, Y, Z); // model need to be a field in your class
```

The other available transorms are :

> 1. ScaleTransform3D
> 2. RotateTransform3D
> 3. MatrixTransform3D
> 4. Transform3DGroup

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is an old question, but right answer might help somebody. The cube gets black because 
 `this.mainViewportChildren.Clear()` 
removes also light source (any of), to make cube get original color you must add to your code something like: 
 `this.mainViewport.Children.Add(new ModelVisual3D() { Content = new AmbientLight(Colors.White) });`

Answer (score 0):

```
//if you use ScreenSpaceLines3D
for (int i = _mainViewport.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    ModelVisual3D modelVisual3D = ModelVisual3D)_mainViewport.Children[i];
    if (modelVisual3D is ScreenSpaceLines3D)
    {
        ScreenSpaceLines3D line3D = ScreenSpaceLines3D)_mainViewport.Children[i];
        line3D.Points.Clear();                             
        continue;

    }
    if (modelVisual3D.Content is DirectionalLight == false)   
    {                
       mainViewport.Children.Remove(modelVisual3D); 
    }                   
}
```